# A LP model for production of two kinds of microphone

Tags: linear-programming

Here is a LP problem:

> A company produces two kinds of microphones: large and small.   The
>   expected demand for the first 3 months of the year is shown below:
>
> The first month : 400 small microphones, 200 large microphones   The
>   second month : 500 small microphones, 320 large microphones    The
>   third month : 550 small microphones, 400 large microphones
>
> At the regular time of working, 1200 large microphones can be produced
>   in a month and at the overtime, 240 large microphones can be produced.
>
> **The production of a large microphone, can be replaced by the production of 2 small microphones. So, if the company produces 199
>   large micrphones, it should 402 small microphones to meet the
>   demand.**
>
> The cost of production of each kind of microphones at the regular time
>   and overtime is shown below:
>
> Small microphone : 60 and 70 units of money (per unit of mic) at the
>   regular time and overtime, respectively.
>   Large microphone : 80 and
>   95 units of money (per unit of mic) at the regular time and overtime,
>   respectively.
>
> The cost of inventory is 3 and 5 units of money ( per unit of mic )
>   for small and large microphones, respectively.
>
> The objective is to meet the demand with the lowest cost.

Provide a Linear-Programming Model for this problem.

Note : My problem is the part that is bolded.  I can't find suitable decision variables because I haven't seen any LP problem like that before. ( The replacement of demands is new for me! )

I would appreciate your answers or even hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Divide the production of large microphones into two cases.

Let $s^r_i$ and $l^r_i$ be the production of small and large microphones during regular time in the $i$-th month ($i \in \{1,2,3\}$) respectively, and $s^o_i$ and $l^o_i$ be the production of small and large microphones during overtime in the $i$-th month ($i \in \{1,2,3\}$) respectively.

Let start with the first month.  Then the other constraints handling demand replacement follows in a similar way.

Case 1: total production of large microphones doesn't meet the original demand 200.  (i.e. $l^r_1 + l^o_1 < 200$)

Then $2(200-(l^r_1 + l^o_1))$ extra small microphones need to be produced, so $s^r_1+s^o_1 \ge 400 + 2(200 - l^r_1 - l^o_1)$.

Case 2: total production of large microphones meets the original demand 200. (i.e. $l^r_1 + l^o_1 \ge 200$)

In the above constraint for $s^r_1+s^o_1$, $200 - l^r_1 - l^o_1$ is *negative* and *unwanted* this case, so we have $s^r_1+s^o_1 \ge 400$.

A *single* inequality generalising these two *different* cases would be $s^r_1+s^o_1 \ge 400 + 2\max\{0,200-l^r_1 - l^o_1\}$, which can be split into *two* linear inequalities

\begin{align}
s^r_1+s^o_1 &\ge 400 \\
s^r_1+s^o_1 &\ge 800 - 2l^r_1 - 2l^o_1.
\end{align}

We can do something similar for the 2nd and 3rd months.

Comment: do i still need to write $l_1^r+l_1^o \ge 200$? or the constraints you wrote are enough?

Comment: Also, you didn't mention the decision variables for inventory!

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade 1. As long as the replacement is allowed, you *can't* omit the first case $l^r_1 + l^o_1 < 200$.  2. How is the cost of inventory per unit of mic calculated?  Per month? Per week?

Comment: Since you've said "My problem is the part that is **bolded**", and the **bolded part** concerns the replacement of demand, and you "appreciate ... hints", I post something like $s_1 \ge 400 + 2 \max\{0,200-l_1\}$ to capture this tricky part.  In fact, if I understand the meaning of "inventory cost" correctly (I think it means storage costs), you may split $l^o_1$ into $l^o_{1,i}, i = 1,2,3$ meaning the number of large microphones produced in the first month during overtime delivered in the $i$-th month.  You may do something similar to other variables.

Comment: And you'll end up with a system with $4 \times 6 = 24$ decision variables $x^t_{i,j}$, where $x \in \{l,s\}$, $t \in \{r,o\}$, $1 \le i \le j \le 3$.